# Parsing data from string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I would like to be able to parse the following data using PHP:

```
$string = "<![CDATA[<div><b>Color:</b> Blue</div>
<div><b>Number:</b> 5</div>
<div><b>Month:</b> January</div>]]>";
```

Into an array such as:

```
Array
(
    [Color] = Blue
    [Number] = 5
    [Month] = January
)
```

I attempted to use preg_match to extract the data between , however, it would not produce any matches.

```
preg_match_all("/\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]]/", $string, $result);
```

I can't get past this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two things, why the `(.*?)` has a `?`. and why haven't you escaped `]` in `\]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=array();
$arr = explode("\n", strip_tags(substr($string,9, strlen($string)-12)));
foreach($arr as $val){
    $tmp = explode(':',$val);
    $result[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```

(Add checks, trims, code style and so on yourself)

Comment: You'd probably want to remove the `<![CDATA[` prior to running `strip_tags()` but other than that this would seem to be a good answer.

Comment: @Spudley thats why there is `substr()`